# Tags not being retained in new navigation

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, new-nav

In using the new navigation if I am looking at the "Need Answer" questions for a tag and then clicking on the "New" questions tab.  The tag that I was filtering by is removed and I see all the new questions.  This behavior happens even if I had started on the "new" tab with my questions filtered by a tag.

I would expect that the tag be retained when choosing between the "new", "popular" and "need answer" tabs.

Comment: Declining: no longer relevant